# How to send the data from the textbox to the controller if the some value from the dropdown list is selected in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a dropdown list. In that have the some values. If the value is not there then user can select the **Other** option in that dropdown list. If **Other** is selected I have to show the textbox. I did this.

My requirement is as follows:

If the option from the dropdown list is selected I want to access this selected value into the controller in a specific variable for example $scope.myvalue. If the Other option is selected then I want to access the value from the textbox to the controller in the same variable, i.e., in $scope.myvalue.

In index.html I have the following code:-

{

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in colors" >
</select>
<input type="text" ng-show="selectedName=='Other'" >
```

}

And in my the controller I have following code

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.colors = ["Black","Red","Orange","Other"];
```

}]);

In the select list I have only three colors Black, Red and Orange. If user wants to select other color then he will select the Other option from the select list. When is selects the **Other** option, a textbox should appear where he can enter color.

Now, If the user has selected the color from the select list, for example **Red** then this should be accessible in the controller in some x variable. If user has selected the **Other** option from the select list a textbox will appear and he will enter some color, for example user has entered **Blue** then this should also be accessible in the controller in the same variable x.
i.e., Whatever value is selected by the user from select list or user has entered the in textbox, I have to take that value in the same variable in a controller.

Comment: what has been tried so far

Comment: Just use `ng-change` on the `<select>` and check model value of the `<select>`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I undertsand your question you have something like this :

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="myController">

<!-- Some code here -->

<select ng-model="myValue">
   <option value="-1">Other</option>
   <option value="100">something</option>
</select>

<!-- Some code here -->

<input type='text' ng-model="myText"/>

</div>
```

And then in your controller.js :

```
myModule.controller('MyController', function($scope){

   $scope.$watch('myValue', function(newValue, oldValue)
   {
        if (newValue == -1)
        {
           $scope.myText = "Other Text";
        }
        else
           $scope.myText = "Something else"; 
   });
});
```

The 'trick' here is to use $scope.$watch which is used to check if a variable in the controller's scope has changed.

Here is the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch